# Remove localhost from url href stored in database

Tags: reactjs

I have a link that is stored in the database. When I clicked on the link, it will include localhost:3000,. For example, I have [www.test.com](http://www.test.com) in database, so it'll be localhost:3000/www.test.com. How to remove the localhost:3000 from the URL?

```
<a href={item.projurl}>{item.projurl}</a>
```

Comment: You need to validate such links that they have a proper protocol ... `http://` or `https://`. You can paste that into browser address bar without it and browser will include it, but not when it is used in an `href`. Without a protocol browser treats it as a relative path on current domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, browsers use [relative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls) URLs.  You either need to store the full URL including the [scheme/protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#scheme) in your database or tell the browser to use an [implicit protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#examples_of_absolute_urls) by prepending `//`.

Implicit protocol

```
const item = {
  projurl: 'www.test.com'
}
<a href={`//${item.projurl}`} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{item.projurl}</a>
```

Full URL

```
const item = {
  projurl: 'http://www.test.com'
}
<a href={item.projurl} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">{item.projurl}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using `https://` right in the beginning of my `img` tag's `src` attribute like this:

```
<img
        src={src ? "https://" + src : EmptyFileIcon}
        alt="logo-image"
        className="bg-white rounded-30 w-full"
/>
```

Now it fetches my image correctly from the server.